# Getting Forbidden (403) in php files located in wp folders

Tags: wordpress

the problem cames when I tried to use the plugin OneSignal, once configured I get errors like "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE", in fact, I get 403 - Forbidden. This is the file which can not be load:

```
wp-content/plugins/onesignal-free-web-push-notifications/sdk_files/OneSignalSDKWorker.js.php
```

I have create the following tests files: (with same permissions and owner)

```
wp-content/test.php // Error 403
test/test.php       // OK, 200
wp-contest/test.php // OK, 200
```

so I came to the conclusion that for some reason, anything is blocking any php file located in /wp-content/ to be loaded.

I already checked .htaccess, I also backed it up and removed it, error persists.
File and folder permissions are also ok, 755 for folder and 644 for files.

I have installed OneSignal several tens of times in different webs and thats the first time I get this error, the site affected is a web that I just migrated from hosting to our vps.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: server firewall is surely to be the culprit if you dont have a security plugin already active

Comment: The same problem with a server configuration? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73935873/4371948